# Not in search string - It works when it is

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you can help.
I have column A and B
In A, I need to replace all text containing "Forsikringspræmie" with "" (Blank)

This code works. Sub KSV_Remove_Forsikringspræmie()

But in Column B, I need the Opposit, to happen. 
And the code Sub KSV_Remove_Not_Forsikringspræmie() dosent work.

```
Sub KSV_Remove_Forsikringspræmie()
    Dim KSV_SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set KSV_SrchRng = Range("A1:A99")
    For Each cel In KSV_SrchRng
      If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Forsikringspræmie") > 0 Then
         cel.Value = ""
      End If
    Next cel
End Sub

Sub KSV_Remove_Not_Forsikringspræmie()
    Dim KSV_SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set KSV_SrchRng = Range("B1:B99")
    For Each cel In KSV_SrchRng
      If InStr(1, cel.Value, Not "Forsikringspræmie") Then
         cel.Value = ""
      End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the `>0` part. This will return a boolean response such that `0 = False` and anything else will be `True`

Comment: Kristian, from your comments, do you want the full cell replaced in A and B or just the string "Forsikringspræmie" replaced in one or the other?

Comment: It would help if you gave examples of a starting string for each column and then show what the result should look like. I think this can be done much faster by working with a filter & visible cells rather a loop

Answer (score 2):

I think you may just be placing the `Not` in the wrong place. Try this:

```
Sub KSV_Remove_Not_Forsikringspræmie()
    Dim KSV_SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set KSV_SrchRng = Range("B1:B99")
    For Each cel In KSV_SrchRng
      If Not (InStr(1, cel.Value, "Forsikringspræmie")) Then
         cel.Value = ""
      End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Greg. It did the trick... THANKS... with one little error it now deletes every cell, since the cells containing "Forsikringspræmie" they are numberede eg. "Forsikringspræmie1, Forsikringspræmie2" etc.... and a wild card dosent work.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to change cel.value from exact to either contains or start with ?

Comment: start with is easy, just use `Left`

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment to Greg's post (comment reads: *with one little error it now deletes every cell, since the cells containing "Forsikringspræmie" they are numberede eg. "Forsikringspræmie1, Forsikringspræmie2" etc.... and a wild card dosent work.*)... if you want to replace and keep the numbers that were in the cell, try the `Replace` function, such that:

```
With Columns(1)
    .Replace what:="Forsikringspræmie", replacement:="", searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
End With
```

Comment: @KristianSveigaard which answer resolved, or more closely resolved your issue?  Please mark one as the answer (green checkbox on the left of the posted answer) or post your own answer to this question.  This will allow the question to be listed as **Solved** when searching as to not have others keep coming back here attempting to resolve your issues.